# how to make a product image clickable and redirect to product details site in wordpress/woocommenrce/uncode theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I couldn't find a tutorial or hint regarding making a product image in the wordpress theme "uncode" clickable. when clicking on the product image, it only opens the image in full size but doesnt rather redirect to the details page.

I assume it isn't a big thing that needs to be changed/added, but finding it seems quite difficult, as I have no experience regarding this theme at all. 
thanks upfront!

**EDIT**: What I am trying to find out, is how to make this (tutorial for another theme https://slocumthemes.com/2015/10/how-to-make-woocommerce-thumbnails-clickable/) for my theme, uncode.

can anybody help? I think I found the line of code in one of the php files, but I have no proper experience of php

Comment: please show your website or screenshot what you exactly want to do? on the product details page show full image of the product which one already on the product details page.

Answer (score 0):

You can override woocommerce template.

1. Create a folder named woocommerce in your uncode theme and further corresponding folders where relevant file is added in woocommmerce plugin. e.g woocommerce/templates/single-product/product-image.php.
2. In that overridden file you can customize the HTML i.e link your image.